# Spacing on Java tax table

Tags: java, spacing

I am making a tax table, and everything is running correctly. However, I am having trouble with the spacing in the body of the table. The spacing under the taxable income, single, and married joint or qualifying widow(er) are fine, but when I get to the married separate, and head of household, the spacing is off. Any idea of what I can do to try to correct this? 
This is what I have so far:

```
//this program prints a tax table
public class PrintTaxTable {      
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //create table header
    System.out.printf("%5s%12s%20s%12s%12s\n", "Taxable", "Single",
      "Married Joint" , "Married", "Head of");
    System.out.printf("%5s%20s%12s%12s%12s\n", "Income", "",  
      "or Qualifying", "Separate", "a house");
    System.out.printf("%20s%15s%12s%20s%20s\n", "", "Widow(er)","", "","");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------" + 
            "-----------------"); 

      // Display table body
    double taxableIncome = 50000;
    while (taxableIncome <= 60000){
    System.out.printf("%5.0f", taxableIncome);
      for (int status = 0; status < 4; status++) {
       // Display the product and align properly
        System.out.printf("%12.0f", computetax(status, taxableIncome));
      }
        System.out.println("");
          taxableIncome = taxableIncome + 50;
                }
            }
        //compute all of the tax rates
        public static double computetax(int status, double taxableIncome) {
            double tax = 0;
            if (status == 0) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 8350)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                 else if (taxableIncome <= 33950)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 8350) * 0.15;
                      else if (taxableIncome <= 82250)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                          (taxableIncome - 33950) * 0.25;           
            }
            else if (status == 1) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 16700)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                    else if (taxableIncome <= 67900)
                        tax = 16700 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 16700) * 0.15;
            }
            else if (status == 2) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 8350)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                 else if (taxableIncome <= 33950)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 8350) * 0.15;
                      else if (taxableIncome <= 68525)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                          (taxableIncome - 33950) * 0.25;
            }
            else if (status == 3) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 11950)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                else if (taxableIncome <= 45500)
                    tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 11950) * 0.15;
                else if (taxableIncome <= 117450)
                    tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (45500 - 11950) * 0.15 +
                    (taxableIncome - 45500) * 0.25;
            }
            return tax;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the status count to your spacing like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintTaxTable {      
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //create table header
    System.out.printf("%5s%12s%20s%12s%12s\n", "Taxable", "Single",
      "Married Joint" , "Married", "Head of");
    System.out.printf("%5s%20s%12s%12s%12s\n", "Income", "",  
      "or Qualifying", "Separate", "a house");
    System.out.printf("%20s%15s%12s%20s%20s\n", "", "Widow(er)","", "","");
    System.out.printf("------------------------------------------------" + 
            "-----------------\n"); 

      // Display table body
    double taxableIncome = 50000;
    while (taxableIncome <= 60000){
    System.out.printf("%5.0f", taxableIncome);
      for (int status = 0; status < 4; status++) {
       // Display the product and align properly
        System.out.printf("%"+(12.0+(status+1))+"f", computetax(status, taxableIncome));
      }
        System.out.print("\n");
          taxableIncome = taxableIncome + 50;
                }
            }
        //compute all of the tax rates
        public static double computetax(int status, double taxableIncome) {
            double tax = 0;
            if (status == 0) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 8350)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                 else if (taxableIncome <= 33950)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 8350) * 0.15;
                      else if (taxableIncome <= 82250)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                          (taxableIncome - 33950) * 0.25;           
            }
            else if (status == 1) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 16700)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                    else if (taxableIncome <= 67900)
                        tax = 16700 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 16700) * 0.15;
            }
            else if (status == 2) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 8350)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                 else if (taxableIncome <= 33950)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 8350) * 0.15;
                      else if (taxableIncome <= 68525)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                          (taxableIncome - 33950) * 0.25;
            }
            else if (status == 3) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 11950)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                else if (taxableIncome <= 45500)
                    tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 11950) * 0.15;
                else if (taxableIncome <= 117450)
                    tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (45500 - 11950) * 0.15 +
                    (taxableIncome - 45500) * 0.25;
            }
            return tax;
        }
}
```

Output is like:

```
Taxable      Single       Married Joint     Married     Head of
Income                    or Qualifying    Separate     a house
                          Widow(er)                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------
50000         8688          6665           8688            7353
50050         8700          6673           8700            7365 ...
```

I hope it helps with the spacing problem.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the spacing issue that I was having.

Answer (score 1):

You need some extra white space after "%12.0f" on line 23:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//this program prints a tax table
public class PrintTaxTable {      
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //create table header
    System.out.printf("%5s%12s%20s%12s%12s\n", "Taxable", "Single",
      "Married Joint" , "Married", "Head of");
    System.out.printf("%5s%20s%12s%12s%12s\n", "Income", "",  
      "or Qualifying", "Separate", "a house");
    System.out.printf("%20s%15s%12s%20s%20s\n", "", "Widow(er)","", "","");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------" + 
            "-----------------"); 

      // Display table body
    double taxableIncome = 50000;
    while (taxableIncome <= 60000){
    System.out.printf("%5.0f", taxableIncome);
      for (int status = 0; status < 4; status++) {
       // Display the product and align properly
        System.out.printf("%12.0f"+"   ", computetax(status, taxableIncome));
      }
        System.out.println("");
          taxableIncome = taxableIncome + 50;

                }
            }
        //compute all of the tax rates
        public static double computetax(int status, double taxableIncome) {
            double tax = 0;
            if (status == 0) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 8350)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                 else if (taxableIncome <= 33950)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 8350) * 0.15;
                      else if (taxableIncome <= 82250)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                          (taxableIncome - 33950) * 0.25;           
            }
            else if (status == 1) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 16700)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                    else if (taxableIncome <= 67900)
                        tax = 16700 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 16700) * 0.15;
            }
            else if (status == 2) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 8350)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                 else if (taxableIncome <= 33950)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 8350) * 0.15;
                      else if (taxableIncome <= 68525)
                        tax = 8350 * 0.10 + (33950 - 8350) * 0.15 +
                          (taxableIncome - 33950) * 0.25;
            }
            else if (status == 3) {
                if (taxableIncome <= 11950)
                    tax = taxableIncome * 0.10;
                else if (taxableIncome <= 45500)
                    tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (taxableIncome - 11950) * 0.15;
                else if (taxableIncome <= 117450)
                    tax = 11950 * 0.10 + (45500 - 11950) * 0.15 +
                    (taxableIncome - 45500) * 0.25;
            }
            return tax;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do something like this earlier, but it wouldn't work for me. I must have missed a double quote or something, because when I put this in it did exactly what I wanted it to do.